# Comparing the efficiency of estimators

Tags: efficiency

I've taken the following explanation from Wikipedia page on efficiency.

---

If $T_1$ and $T_2$ are estimators for the parameter $\theta$, then $T_1$ is said to ''dominate'' $T_2$ if:

1. Its mean squared error (MSE) is smaller for at least some value of $\theta$
2. The MSE does not exceed that of $T_2$ for any value of $\theta$.

Formally, $T_1$ dominates $T_2$ if
$
\mathrm{E}
\left[
 (T_1 - \theta)^2
\right]
\leq
\mathrm{E}
\left[
 (T_2-\theta)^2
\right]
$

holds for all $\theta$, with strict inequality holding somewhere.

---

My question is, how can this hold for all $\theta$? Isn't there only one value of $\theta$? If $\theta$ is a parameter isn't it's value fixed at a single unknown quantity? Or does the formula imply that the estimators are compared across different populations which all of which have an important defining parameter which is called $\theta$?

Comment: Sure, there's just one value for $\theta$. But, *since you don't know what that value is,* you need to compare statistical procedures based on how they perform *for any possible value of $\theta$.*  Think in terms of game theory: it's a two-person game between you and nature.  Nature chooses $\theta$ and you will guess $\theta$ to be $\hat\theta$. Your payoff depends on the discrepancy between $\theta$ and $\hat\theta$. What is your best strategy? When you investigate that, you have to consider all possible choices made by nature.

Comment: @whuber "But, since you don't know what that value is, you need to compare statistical procedures based on how they perform for any possible value of $\theta$" Thanks, that makes it a lot clearer. The game theory also makes sense given that the wiki example even talks about one estimator "dominating" the other. As always, great answer whuber